# php imap access with gsuite

Tags: php, google-workspace

I am able to use imap_open() with a standard `name@gmail.com` address, however I have another account which is using gsuite, so I have a `name@mydomain.com` address, which will not connect.

I have enabled imap access on the gsuite account.

I have enabled "less secure apps" on the gsuite account.

```
$username_A = 'thisWorks@gmail.com'
$username_B = 'thisDoesNotWork@myDomain.com'
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$inbox_A = imap_open($hostname,$username_A,$password)
$inbox_B = imap_open($hostname,$username_B,$password)
```

What else do I need to do in order to enable imap access via php to my Gsuite account?